how to fix bad request error in platform.sh
im learning web deployment using platform.sh. i pushed my files to platform.sh by command "platform push" and then supposed to get my live url by commanding "platform url" i got some list of urls but in the browser it is showing error 502 "bad gateway" i tried every thing from checking internet connections, updating CLI,DNS etc. is there any command im missing or any pushing issues? help out guys.
this is routes.yaml
# Each route describes how an incoming URL will be processed by Platform.sh.
"https://{default}/":
  type: upstream
  upstream: "ll_project:http"
  
"https://www.{default}/":
  type: redirect
  to: "https://{default}/"



expectation!


when i commanded "platform url" after "platform push", im supposed to get some list of urls and chose 1 out of them to be my web address according to the book "python crash course by erric maththes" latest edition page no 456. But i was promted 4 urls and no option to select. when i copied all the urls in my brave browser i got error 502 "bad request" in every site.
